# How to implement custom binding of query string parameters for ASP.NET Core minimal API

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have been battling with this all day and have now resorted to StackOverflow in an attempt to get some sense. I have an end point that allows my users to be listed, searched and paged and I originally had these configured as a MapGet but I then realised in Postman I was submitting them with a request body which the Internet seems to argue about constantly but the general consensus is that this is not what is expected so should be avoided.

So this led me to refactor my list methods to use a GET method that only uses the query string parameters to supply the required parameters that control what data is returned to the client.

Here's my route mapping: -

```
        group.MapGet("get-users", GetUsers)
            .WithName(nameof(this.GetUsers))
            .RequirePermission(Permission.Users, PermissionLevel.Viewer);
```

Here's my API function: -

```
    private async Task<Results<Ok<ListResponse<UserResponse>>, NotFound<Error>>> GetUsers(
        [FromQuery]ListUserRequest request,
        ISender sender,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var query = new ListUserQuery(
            request.SearchPhrase,
            request.ListParams);

        Result<ListResponse<UserResponse>> response = await sender.Send(query, cancellationToken);

        return response.IsSuccess ?
            TypedResults.Ok(response.Value) :
            TypedResults.NotFound(response.Error);
    }
```

As you can see I have class that holds the page, active and sorting configuration which are consistent across all list endpoints that I have.

```
        public ListQueryParameters(
            int page,
            int pageSize,
            bool includeUnactive,
            string? sortColumn,
            SortOrder sortOrder)
        {
            this.Page = page;
            this.PageSize = pageSize;
            this.IncludeUnactive = includeUnactive;
            this.SortColumn = sortColumn;
            this.SortOrder = sortOrder;
        }
```

I have read this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/parameter-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0 and implemented a TryParse method on my ListUserRequest class i.e.: -

```
    public static bool TryParse(string? qs, out ListUserRequest request)
    {
        request = new ListUserRequest();

        var queryString = QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(qs);
        if (queryString.TryGetValue(QueryStringParameterNames.SearchPhrase, out StringValues searchPhrase))
        {
            request.SearchPhrase = searchPhrase.ToString();
        }

        request.ListParams = new ListQueryParameters();

        if (queryString.TryGetValue(QueryStringParameterNames.ListQueryParameters.Page, out StringValues page))
        {
            request.ListParams.Page = System.Convert.ToInt32(page.ToString());
        }

        [Further Code]
}
```

However, I just get the following error: -

```
[15:06:44 ERR] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.BadHttpRequestException: Required parameter "ListUserRequest request" was not provided from query string.
   at lambda_method119(Closure, Object, HttpContext)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anybody stumbles across this it might save you some pain. My API endpoints are all async so I think you must use the alternative BindAsync static method approach: -

```
    public static ValueTask<ListUserRequest> BindAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        var request = new ListUserRequest();

        var queryString = QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(context.Request.Query.ToString());
        if (queryString.TryGetValue(QueryStringParameterNames.SearchPhrase, out StringValues searchPhrase))
        {
            request.SearchPhrase = searchPhrase.ToString();
        }

        request.ListParams = new ListQueryParameters();

        if (queryString.TryGetValue(QueryStringParameterNames.ListQueryParameters.Page, out StringValues page))
        {
            request.ListParams.Page = Convert.ToInt32(page.ToString());
        }

        if (queryString.TryGetValue(QueryStringParameterNames.ListQueryParameters.PageSize, out StringValues pageSize))
        {
            request.ListParams.PageSize = Convert.ToInt32(pageSize.ToString());
        }

        [Other Code]

        return ValueTask.FromResult(request);
    }
```

So the BindAsync method goes inside the ListUserRequest class, it is documented but it doesn't explicitly say you need to use one or other.